# Feign Fallback is not working with Springboot 2.7.11

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, fallback, openfeign

After Migrating the spring boot version from 2.0.8.RELEASE to 2.7.11 the feign fallback is not working.

facing below error
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException$InternalServerError: [500 Internal Server Error] during [GET] to [https://sampleurl/test] []: [Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 - Error report<!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans... (1177 bytes)]

I am using below code

```
@FeignClient(name = "myFeign", fallbackFactory = MyFeignClientFallbackFactory.class)
public interface MyFeignClient {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    String getValue(@RequestParam("param1") String param1);
}
```

fallback factory class

```
@Component
public class MyFeignClientFallbackFactory implements FallbackFactory<MyFeignClientFallback> {

    @Override
    public MyFeignClientFallback create(Throwable cause) {
        return new MyFeignClientFallback(cause);
    }

}
```

Fallback class

```
@Slf4j
public class MyFeignClientFallback implements MyFeignClient{

    
    private final Throwable cause;

    public MyFeignClientFallback(Throwable cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(String param1) {
        mapErrorResponse("param1");
        return null;
    }
   private void mapErrorResponse(String methodName) {
        log.error("Error while calling feign method " + methodName);
    }
```

I am using springboot 2.7.11 with java 11 and spring cloud 2021.0.1 version

dependencies for feign client

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Ribbon is not compatible with that version of spring cloud. Please use spring cloud loadbalancer